# Unity object follow another object direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector

I have two objects in my 2d game. One (pet) need to follow another object(player) position. Here is my code

```
 void Update()
 {
     direction = (player.position - transform.position).normalized;
     transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime * petSpeed);
 }
```

My problem is pet object direction ( rotation) . When pet is child of player, pet direction works fine(rotate as player rotate), but when pet is outside player object pet, pet not rotating as player.

I don't want pet to be child object of Player.

Can some one tell me why direction don't work when pet is not child of player?

Thanks

Comment: This should work, at least works in 3D. Is there any other code messing with the follower?

Comment: Well currently you only set its position via `transform.Translate` ... You don't assign a new rotation at all ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends a bit what you are trying to do but currently you set a new position via `transform.Translate` but you **don't** set a new rotation at all ...

You could probably e.g. do something like

```c#
void Update()
{
    direction = (player.position - transform.position).normalized;
    transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime * petSpeed);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
}
```

see [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)

Or if you want it a bit smoother

```c#
void Update()
{
    direction = (player.position - transform.position).normalized;
    transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime * petSpeed);

    var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, 0.5f);
}
```

see [`Quaternion.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html) or also [`Quaternion.Slerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html)

Note that both options still allow the pet to move "side-wards", not in the direction it is looking to ;)